# my onClick function is working when i use mouse click , but when i use the keyboard , it is not working . any suggestions how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onkeypress, google-places-autocomplete

so basically , I am using react-places-autocomplete , and i'm trying to call on click function when the user click on one of the address suggestions . it is working when i use the mouse but it is not working when i use the keyboard. 
 please check my code

I have tried onSelect onKeyPressed and they didnt work .

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./Location.css";

import PlacesAutocomplete, { geocodeByAddress,getLatLng } from "react-places-autocomplete";

import { Paper, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

function AddLocation(props) {

    //here is the function

    const handleClick = () => {

        console.log("the function is called ");

    };

    return (
    <Paper elevation="5">

      <div style={{ padding: 10 }}>

        <PlacesAutocomplete
          value={address}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onClick={handleChange}
        >
          {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, load }) => (
            <>
              <TextField
                id="outlined-name"
                label="Address"
                error={errors.address}
                value={address}
                helperText={errors.address}
                name="name"
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
                variant="outlined"
                {...getInputProps({
                  placeholder: "Search Places ...",
                  className: "location-search-input"
                })}
              />
              <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                {load && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                  const className = suggestion.active
                    ? "suggestion-item--active"
                    : "suggestion-item";
                  const style = suggestion.active
                    ? {
                        backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                        cursor: "pointer"
                      }
                    : {
                        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                        cursor: "pointer"
                      };
                  return (
                    <div
                      {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                        className,
                        style
                      })}
                    >
                      {/* /////////////////here is my onClick//////////////  */}
                      <div onClick={handleClick}>
                        <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                      </div>
                      {/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */}
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </PlacesAutocomplete>
      </div>
    </Paper>
    );
}

export default AddLocation;
```

I expect the mouseclick and keyboardclick to call my function when i click on one the suggestions

Comment: How are you trying to select a `div` to click with keyboard? Maybe make it into an anchor (`a`) or something else that’s focusable?

Comment: onKeyPress? not OnKeyPressed

Comment: `onClick` triggers only mouse click and touch tap. To trigger keyboard use `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp`.

Comment: Maybe `onKeyDown` or I think there is `onFocus`

Comment: thank you for your comments But it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Someone had the same issue than you on `react-places-autocomplete` repo : [here](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete/issues/208).
The solution :

```
const inputProps = getInputProps({ placeholder: locationPlaceholder });

const onKeyDown = (event) => {
  const suggestionsOpen = !!suggestions.length; // find out if suggestions are active or not
  inputProps.onKeyDown(event); // do the normal onKeyDown callback
  if(!suggestionsOpen && event.keyCode === 13){ // if this is enter key, submit form
    this.submitForm(); 
  }
}

<input type="text" {...inputProps} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
```